# which file generated after compilation in C#?

Tags: file, compiled

i want to know that after compiling the file in C# which type of file is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have to depend on the type of project.  If it is a console application it will be an exe file.  If there are multiple projects and one console app then the other projects will be compiled as DLL files.  Obviously this doesn't include web projects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a .dll or a .exe is the answer you are looking for